# How to position UIButton to extreme right of UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, user-interface, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to adjust UIToolBar left and right padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021138/how-to-adjust-uitoolbar-left-and-right-padding)

As you see in the attached picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92pK9.png), there is a bit of padding of some kind preventing the UIButton from going all the way to the right. 
How do I position the button all the way to the right so it's touching the right of the screen?

Comment: You can use the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7042201/772156 Basically, put a UIBarButtonItem with fixed space and set the width negative.

Comment: One of the other answers(the one by TonyMocha) on that thread helped me. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Use `flexible Space Bar Button` before the button in xib or Storyboard.

Comment: I tried this(see attached picture), but the toolbar has some padding that prevents elements from being positioned all the way left/right. 
@hukir's answer helped me, I was able to solve it programmatically.