# How to add two custom rightBarButtonItems without a margin between them?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

I create UIToolbar with interface builder and want to add two custom right buttons, but without a space between them. I don't want solution to reset a margin from the right edge, because I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021138/how-to-adjust-uitoolbar-left-and-right-padding) but want only reset margin between buttons.

How should I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a button, use an UISegmentedControl and set its momentary property to yes.
Add one segment for each button you want (in this case two segments)
Then add an IBAction and use a switch to know what index has been selected.
Index 0 first button, index 1 second button.

Answer (score 1):

Create a bar button item with a custom view where that custom view has 2 `UIButton`s as subviews. In this way you can exactly size and position the buttons as you require.

Comment: The issue here will be mimicking the look/feel/behavior of a UIBarButtonItem with a UIButton.  Always a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

To adjust space between `UIBarButtonItem's` you can use a `UIBarButtonItem` with style `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` and setting its `width` property.

You can move items closer to eachother than the default spacing by setting the width of the spacer item to be a negative value.

One thing to consider is future-proofing whichever solution you choose.  Buttons in iOS6 have nice borders and shading.  They may not in the near future...

Comment: I need buttons to be custom views. I use negative width for button which removes right edge margin. Placing such button between my custom buttons will not have any effect.

Comment: Actually it will have effect.  I've used this trick to space custom buttons and it works fine.