# Spacing between two barButtons in Navigation Bar-ios

Tags: ios, navigationbar

iOS
I have three right bar buttons items in my navigation Bar.
I want to change the default spacing between them to zero, so that all the buttons stick to each other?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a spacer (`UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace`) with a negative value. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7042201/517832) for more details.

Another approach could be using a custom item with a smaller size than its content then allowing drawing outside out of its bounds using [`UIView.clipToBounds`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds) property.