# Set default Fixed Space UIBarButtonItem width

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

Basically, the title says everything. I'm trying to do some customization and i need to use less-than-zero width to make buttons be closer to each other.

I've learned it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8070763/1280800).

I can do it by manually setting every fixed space width, but how can I do it via [appearance] or something to make it default?

Something like this:

```
// works for every button not only Fixed Space
[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setWidth:-10];
```

**!!! OR  !!!**

How can i set less-than-zero width in XCode? I'm creating everything using Storyboard anyway, it says that's not a valid value to set.

Any help would be really great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally solve this kind of problem by subclassing the container and overriding `layoutSubviews` or `didLayoutSubviews`. This gives you a lot of control of all kind of styling behavior. In this particular case you would determine the widths programmatically and adjust the frames accordingly.

Make your instance class a subclass of this subclass, and you will have the layout code neatly separated from your implementation.

Comment: Thanks! Can I avoid the subclassing? It just feels bad for me to subclass something that I use only in storyboard GUI for 1 line of code... :)

Comment: If you do not plan on reusing this, you can just override these methods in your original subclass.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I actually need to reuse them about 10 or more times... Not in code, but in storyboard, on different screens.

Comment: Then you should make a separate subclass as the parent of all your instances. In storyboard, you can easily assign this class to your storyboard objects.

Comment: Yeah, now doing this. Should i override the `initWithCoder` method to set width here? Thanks for helping!

Comment: I usually define my own `doInit` task and call that in `init`, `initWithCoder` and any other common initializers like `initWithTitle:etc`.